# Simplify my javascript click add/toggle/remove class

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I am working on a section on my website where I need to toggle, add, and remove a class.

I have something that works really good but I was wondering if there is a simple solution to make my code better, organized, and much more readable than how it is now.

I have 4 buttons:

> .info-button-left-1

> .info-button-left-2

> .info-button-right-1

> .info-button-right-2

These buttons trigger a class to ad to the following divs:

> .product-information-block-left-1

> .product-information-block-left-2

> .product-information-block-right-1

> .product-information-block-right-2

And this is my code:

```
   <?php
// Create id attribute allowing for custom "anchor" value.
$id = 'info-product-block-' . $block['id'];
if( !empty($block['anchor']) ) {
    $id = $block['anchor'];
}

// Create class attribute allowing for custom "className" and "align" values.
$className = 'info-product-block';
if( !empty($block['className']) ) {
    $className .= ' ' . $block['className'];
}
if( !empty($block['align']) ) {
    $className .= ' align' . $block['align'];
}
 ?>


<section id="<?php echo esc_attr($id); ?>" class="<?php echo esc_attr($className); ?> container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
   <div class="container">
     <div class="row product-heading">
       <div class="col">
         <h2><?php echo the_field('product_heading'); ?></h2>
         <?php echo the_field('product_content'); ?>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row product-information">
       <div class="col-left-product">
         <div class="left">
           <div class="product-name"><?php echo the_field('product_name_left'); ?></div>
           <div class="product-year"><?php echo the_field('product_year_left'); ?></div>
           <div class="product-button">
             <?php
             $link = get_field('product_link_left');
             if( $link ):
                 $link_url = $link['url'];
                 $link_title = $link['title'];
                 $link_target = $link['target'] ? $link['target'] : '_self';
                 ?>
                 <a class="buy-button" href="<?php echo esc_url( $link_url ); ?>" target="<?php echo esc_attr( $link_target ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $link_title ); ?></a>
             <?php endif; ?>
           </div>
         </div>
         <div class="right">
           <div class="product-image">
             <div class="info-button-left-1"></div>
             <div class="info-button-left-2"></div>
             <?php
             $image = get_field('product_image_left');
             if( !empty( $image ) ): ?>
                 <img src="<?php echo esc_url($image['url']); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr($image['alt']); ?>" />
             <?php endif; ?>
           </div>
           <div class="product-information-block-left-1">
             <?php echo the_field('product_content_left'); ?>
           </div>
           <div class="product-information-block-left-2">
             <?php echo the_field('product_content_left'); ?>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-right-product">
         <div class="right">
           <div class="product-image">
             <div class="info-button-right-1"></div>
             <div class="info-button-right-2"></div>
             <?php
             $image_right = get_field('product_image_right');
             if( !empty( $image_right ) ): ?>
                 <img src="<?php echo esc_url($image_right['url']); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr($image_right['alt']); ?>" />
             <?php endif; ?>
           </div>
           <div class="product-information-block-right-1">
             <?php echo the_field('product_content_left'); ?>
           </div>
           <div class="product-information-block-right-2">
             <?php echo the_field('product_content_left'); ?>
           </div>
         </div>
         <div class="left">
           <div class="product-name"><?php echo the_field('product_name_right'); ?></div>
           <div class="product-year"><?php echo the_field('product_year_right'); ?></div>
           <div class="product-button">
             <?php
             $link_right = get_field('product_link_right');
             if( $link_right ):
                 $link_right_url = $link_right['url'];
                 $link_right_title = $link_right['title'];
                 $link_right_target = $link_right['target'] ? $link_right['target'] : '_self';
                 ?>
                 <a class="buy-button" href="<?php echo esc_url( $link_right_url ); ?>" target="<?php echo esc_attr( $link_right_target ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $link_right_title ); ?></a>
             <?php endif; ?>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
<script>
$(".col-left-product .info-button-left-1").click(function() {
    $(".product-information-block-left-1").toggleClass("active");
    $(".product-information-block-left-2").removeClass("active");
    $(".product-information-block-right-1").removeClass("active");
    $(".product-information-block-right-2").removeClass("active");
});
$(".col-left-product .info-button-left-2").click(function() {
    $(".product-information-block-left-2").toggleClass("active");
    $(".product-information-block-left-1").removeClass("active");
    $(".product-information-block-right-1").removeClass("active");
    $(".product-information-block-right-2").removeClass("active");
});

$(".col-right-product .info-button-right-1").click(function() {
    $(".product-information-block-right-1").toggleClass("active");
    $(".product-information-block-right-2").removeClass("active");
    $(".product-information-block-left-1").removeClass("active");
    $(".product-information-block-left-2").removeClass("active");
});
$(".col-right-product .info-button-right-2").click(function() {
    $(".product-information-block-right-2").toggleClass("active");
    $(".product-information-block-right-1").removeClass("active");
    $(".product-information-block-left-1").removeClass("active");
    $(".product-information-block-left-2").removeClass("active");
});
</script>
</section>
```

I am learning more and more every day. but I do think that there is a better way to do this.
Is there anyone who can give me an answer or a path to follow?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you edit the question to include the actual HTML.

Comment: The code is now in the question

Comment: Are you SURE you should be using `toggleClass` instead of `addClass` there?

Comment: @TKoL that's actually a really good one. But I want the visitor to also be able to close the same block when they click on the same button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the JS more generic you can use common class names on the elements. Then you can relate them to each other by using DOM traversal methods, such as `closest()` and `find()` to target the required element by matching indexes. Something like this:

```js
let $productInfoBlocks = $('.product-information-block');

$('.info-button').on('click', e => {
  let $el = $(e.target);
  let $targetInfoBlock = $el.closest('.col').find('.product-information-block').eq($el.index()).toggleClass('active');
  $productInfoBlocks.not($targetInfoBlock).removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active { color: #C00; }
```

```html
<!-- Note: I reduced the HTML to the relevant elements only -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row product-information">
  <div class="col col-left-product">
    <div class="right">
      <div class="product-image">
        <div class="info-button">info-button-left-1</div>
        <div class="info-button">info-button-left-2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="product-information-block">product-information-block-left-1</div>
      <div class="product-information-block">product-information-block-left-2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col col-right-product">
    <div class="right">
      <div class="product-image">
        <div class="info-button">info-button-right-1</div>
        <div class="info-button">info-button-right-2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="product-information-block">product-information-block-right-1</div>
      <div class="product-information-block">product-information-block-right-2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is actually really good. But how can I use this when I click on the ```.right > .product-image > .info-button-#``` to all remove the class from the ```.left``` block?

Comment: Ah, I missed that requirement. In that case it simplifies the logic slightly. I updated the answer for you

Answer (score 0):

In similar case I used data attribute in combination with a general class name:

The general syntax for buttons:

```
<div class="info-button" data-place="left" data-targetId="1"></div>
```

The general code for target divs:

```
<div class="product-information-block" data-place="right" data-targetId="1">
    <?php echo the_field('product_content_left'); ?>
</div>
```

The general code to handle all occurances:

```
$(".col-right-product .info-button").click(function() {
    var place=$(this).data("place");
    var targetId=$(this).data("targetId");
    $(".product-information-block").removeClass("active");
    $(".product-information-block[data-place='"+ place +"'][data-targetId='"+ targetId +"']").addClass("active");
});
```